# What is the meaning of this proposition by Robert Daublebsky von Sterneck?

Tags: number-theory, math-history

I found something wrong with this proposition, but I'm not sure.

Would you help me understand this proposition?  Thanks for all.

Can you give me **an example**?  It couldn't be better.

Cf. *History of the Theory of Numbers, Volume II* P152

> **English translation:** He proved also that, if k is not a triangular number and if we represent k as a sum of integers so that the same part is not used oftener than 3 times in the same representation, then among the representations which contain ρ distinct parts less often than 3 times there are as many sums of even as of odd parts.

&

> **Original text:** Ist k keine Trigonalzahl und stellt man k derart als Summe von ganzen Zahlen dar, dass eine und dieselbe Zahl bis zu dreimal, jedoch nicht öfter, in einer und derselben Darstellung verwendet werden darf, so gibt es unter den Darstellungen, welche ρ verschiedene Elemente weniger oft als dreimal enthalten, gleich viele gerade wie ungerade für jeden gegebenen Werth des ρ.

https://archive.org/details/HistoryOfTheTheoryOfNumbersVolII/page/n177

https://www.zobodat.at/pdf/SBAWW_106_2a_0115-0122.pdf